# AngularJS: All buttons inside form triggers submit?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I apologize in advance if this is covered in the docs, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a pretty straightforward form which uses several buttons as I'm using twitter bootstrap. The problem is that clicking any of the buttons in the form seems to trigger a submit event to angular: In my form there are several input fields in which I use the "require" attribute and so clicking any button opens a dialog saying the field is required. This is all well and good, except I only want the validation to take place when the user clicks the actual submit button.

I have tried setting the ng-submit to a function which so far only returns false, but this did not seem to have any effect.

**Update:** I've found a temporary workaround using a directive which uses event.preventDefault(). However this seems a bit excessive and also means I have to attach it to every button.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <form ng-submit="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="katana-technician-form">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Tekniker
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input type="text" class="span2" />
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <!-- Triggers onSubmit-->
                                            <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Velg<span class="caret"></span>

                                            </button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>Kake</li>
                                                <li>Bake</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <!-- Triggers onSubmit-->
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You should try setting `type="button"` on the buttons.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms) goes into detail as to what this does.

Comment: Pulling my hair out over this one for over an hour... Thanks!

Comment: I always wondered what type="button" is needed for, now I got a reason why. Thank you!