# Angularjs Many Buttons in same form with different actions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two small questions:

**First problem:**
I have an simple form with two buttons (add information and cancel information). The Add information button submit send some information by http post. The cancel information does a `location.path` to other page.

It turns out that the "cancel info" button does not work when i click.

Second problem:
Using the same form, when i click in Add information it shows a div success with a message. I wish, if that div is displayed, the add information button disappears (does not work )

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="informationController">
<form name="exampleForm" class="form-vertical col-md-12"  ng-submit="addInformation()">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="sucessAdd!=''" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Success:</span> {{sucessAdd}}
  </div>
</div> 
</div> 

<div class="form-group">                                       
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="col-md-3">
   <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info" ng-hide="sucessAdd!=''"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Add info</button> 
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button   class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-hand-right" ng-click="go()" ></i>Cancel info</button> 
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
controller('informationController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.sucessAdd="";

    $scope.addInformation = function() { 

        if("information is sent successfully") {
            $scope.sucessAdd='Information created sucessfully!!';
        }

        $scope.go = function() {      
            $location.path("/pathToDefine");
        };
    }
});
```

so, anyone can help me?? :)

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your dev console?

Comment: add type="button" for second button  "Cancel info" by default the type of button is submit.

Comment: Did you try clicking on your cancel icon? (icon-hand-right) Your `ng-click` is on the `i` not on the `button`.

Comment: Please refere this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687921/angularjs-all-buttons-inside-form-triggers-submit"

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag instead of button.

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="go()"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i>Cancel info</a>
```

And use `ng-click` on anchor tag instead.